# Is there any way to check which wordpress categories was created by which user?

Tags: categories, users

Showing users only those categories which was created by them only. I tried to find relations between categories and users in database but couldn't find any.

Comment: WordPress, by default, doesn't keep track of category authors.

Comment: You can add you own logic in term metadata!

Comment: yes i did that, i created a term meta with meta key as say 'useridmetakey' with meta value of the userid(value) while creating the categories but couldn't able to find how to customize the category listing page by using my own mysql query

Comment: Then edit your question and add what you want and what is your code that you've done so far!

Comment: actually i want to know  is there any hook for wordpress categories listing page so that i can add a my custom callback function with that hook and add extra field named as 'Created user' and show the name of the user corresponding to that categories

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't do this out of the box. So if you want to know about something that has already happened you're too late :)

But if you'd like to know in the future you could for instance have a look at this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-audit-log/